# Proxy Rotator Captchas?

Tags: python, proxy, request, ip, captcha

I have made a working python proxy rotator to avoid captchas.

I can verify that the proxies are taking hold because I make a request to a site that gets me my IP, and it's different each time.

However, the response headers tell me that I need to answer to their captcha. This wouldn't be a problem due to high traffic on these proxies, but, the problem is, I have even tried connecting those https proxies to my computer, and then signing up, and it does so without a captcha.

I have tried everything; even copying every single header word for word. Is it possible that the site could see my real IP and using that as a basis for captchas?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [anti-captcha.com](http://anti-captcha.com) for quite a while and I'm happy with it, they charge about 0.7USD per 1000 images, which is quite affordable.

To install it use:

```
pip install antigate
```

[Antigate Python Usage](https://github.com/gotlium/antigate#usage)